# What challenges might I expect from switching to online DMing from exclusively tabletop?

Tags: gm-techniques, online-roleplaying

Because of COVID-19 our exclusively in-person sessions are going entirely online. We have downloaded roll 20, and we have voice chat, but beyond that we are fish out of water in the new medium.

What challenges might I expect from switching to online DMing from exclusively tabletop?

Comment: I'm sorry but our site does not handle questions that ask for open-ended ideas. You'll have better responses from [chat].

Comment: Related: [How can I better prepare my players for roleplaying online?](/questions/126072), [How can I interest a player in playing online?](/questions/125736), [Online play: How to keep the group focused?](/questions/125636), [How to improve player engagement in video call for virtual tabletop game?](/questions/90355/), [How to facilitate equal speaking opportunity in a voice-only online game](/questions/96270)

Comment: Asking for "any tips or tricks" is *way* too broad for this site to answer. What sort of challenges are you facing or expecting?  Player interaction? Converting material to online format?

Comment: @MikeQ we've never done it before so we don't know what to expect. Is "what challenges might I expect from switching to online DMing from exclusively tabletop?" less broad

Comment: FWIW, my group is in quite similar situation, and I'm sure many others are too. It would be great if this question can be formulated so that it fits this QA format, because the question is very relevant right now!

Comment: @kent Our site is very good at addressing actual problems that are actually happening, but not very well suited to questions that amount to "come up with all the possible problems that could happen" (see our [questions to avoid asking](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)). I suggest rather than try to anticipate any number of potential problems, try your session and ask us about any problems you *do* experience.

Comment: @doppelganger okay, will do.